# ASUS UX305CA - scratching/rattling/HDD-like noises

Tags: laptop, noise

I bought an ASUS UX305CA specifically because I wanted a laptop that does not make any noise (fan, HDD), as I like to work in rather quiet environments for hours, and such noises can be super disturbing.

I run a dual boot on it, stock Windows 10 alongside Ubuntu 16.10.

Lately I have noticed a rattling noise coming from the right side of the keyboard. It seems to increase under load, as though it was writing to/reading from an HDD. However, given it has an SSD installed and no fan, I fail to understand where ANY sound, but this one in particular, could be coming from.

Does anyone here have similar issue? Or can anyone think of anything that might cause this noise? I do like this notebook, and the sound is not too loud. but having to listen to music in order to not hear it defeats the purpose of having a super silent notebook.

Comment: Maybe some insect inside? Or corrupted speaker? Or you got scammed and it does have a HDD inside.

Comment: This can be manufacturer's economy on extra capacitors or digital and analog "ground" incorrectly routed on PCB that allows voltage pulsations under heavy loading bypass to analog amplifier that serve speakers.

Comment: Thanks for the quick comments!
Hex : Didn t see anything that would (insects, anything loose) and cause that noise when opening up. I checked and it does have an SDD installed - and HDD wouldn t even fit :)

@Alex : I wouldn t even know how to start testing for that. Any straight forward way to check for that?

Comment: @chimp Try disconnecting the speakers from motherboard, if it's possible.

Comment: I moved my comments to the answer field because this maximum characters restriction annoy me.

Answer (score 0):

This can be manufacturer's economy on extra capacitors or digital and analog "ground" incorrectly routed on PCB that allows voltage pulsations under heavy loading bypass to analog amplifier that serve speakers.

Try to spot source of that noise. If my suggestion is right it should comes from speakers. If you have someone where you can barrow phonendoscope it will help in your case. Another choice, - if you Ok with disassembling the case of computer then disconnecting speakers probably is the first step to spot this issue. If you will decide to open computer's case, check also all spots around inverters or to be precise - its coils (it could looks like a small cubes). If wire wasn't rolled tight enough then under heavy load wires may start moving under magnetic force that may create such annoying noise. Simple solution to fix it - is to use hot glue if you can reach coil.